# Trouble using the leaflet package to make an interactive map using the us.cities package

Tags: r, leaflet, label, markers

I am trying to make an interactive graph of the United States using leaflet and the us.cities package in R. I was able to create the map and label put markers on all the US capitals, but I am struggling to label those capitals on the map itself.

The goal is to be able to click on a marker and have the state capital and population appear on the graph. The trouble is steaming from my last section of code that starts with the #. If anyone has any idea why that code will not run, besides the obvious fact that I put a # in front, I am open to any and all guidance!

Thank you!

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)

leaflet(us.cities) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(data = us.cities)

us.cities <- us.cities %>% filter(capital == 2) %>% mutate(state_info = paste(name, capital == 2, pop))

us.cities$state_info

#leaflet(us.cities) %>% addTiles() %>% addCircleMarkers(data = us.cities, lat = ~lat, lng = ~long, state_info = ~state_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the `leaflet` package, but for the purposes of providing a quick answer...

```
leaflet(us.cities) %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(
        data = us.cities, 
        lat = ~lat, 
        lng = ~long, 
        popup = paste(us.cities$country.etc, us.cities$pop)
    )
```